# How can I reduce latency between my AWS EC2 instance and another AWS customer's REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a need to reduce the latency for my application to reach a vendor's API. Currently my EC2 instance resides in the same region and availability zone as the vendor and I am using EC2 instances with the best network performance.

Is there anything else within my control that I can do to reduce the latency between my application and the vendor's API?

If I had the vendor's cooperation, could anything be done to further reduce the latency?

Comment: Maybe you could keep the connection open if possible (keep-alive)

Comment: What kind of latency are we talking about? 0.5ms? 5ms? 50ms? 500ms?  How much of the latency accounts for each part of the transaction (TCP handshake, TLS handshake, HTTP TTFB)?  What has the vendor said about the latency? There's really not enough information provided to answer without guessing.  Also... *"Currently my EC2 instance resides in the same region and availability zone as the vendor?"*  How do you know this?  *My* us-east-1b may or may not be *your* us-east-1b (the odds vary but this is statistically unlikely in most cases if you are working from the labels displayed to you).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ways to reduce latency:

- Connect to resources **in the same region**: You are doing this
- Connect to resources **in the same Availability Zone**: While you say that you are doing this, it might not be so simple. Each AWS account has a random naming of AZs, so you might not actually be in the same AZ.
- Connect via **VPC Peering**: This bypasses the Internet Gateway and the mapping of Public IP addresses. The vendor would need to invite you to join and you would accept the peering request (or vice versa).

Or, the new modern option:

- Connect via [**AWS PrivateLink**](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/introducing-aws-privatelink-for-aws-services/), which exposes an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) within your VPC that directly connects to a Network Load Balancer in the vendor's VPC.

Any further optimization would require more information about the work being performed and the current architecture. For example, a **queue** might be more efficient than sending direct messages, or perhaps the use of **streaming data** might be more appropriate, depending upon the type of data being sent. (Feel free to Edit your question with more details if you want a more accurate answer.)

Comment: Does it possible to use AWS PrivateLink between my instance and another one that i don't own or have any control of it (only have their public IP)?

Comment: @user2203703 No, it won't help you to do that. You should connect to it via its public IP address.